# what does this symbol mean in chinese?

Tags: traditional-characters

[image]

I saw a random image of Chinese character. Can someone tell me what letter it is. I had often seen it as a mysterious symbol. So where does one use this symbol? Is it spiritual or zen kind of symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「美」

This character is written as "mei3" in pinyin and is pronounced similarly to the English word "May" (like the month).

It generally means "beautiful".

Answer (score 1):

This Chinese character means "beauty" or "good". The pinyin of this word is měi.

You can make the common Chinese phrases, such as 
"美丽" měi lì （beautiful）; 
"美国" měi guó (America); 
"美味" měi wèi (delicious).

The stroke order is
[image]

If you think it's so hard to remember this Chinese character, you can see this video and learn how to learn Chinese Characters by associative memory.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtH96dJdUpk

Comment: There are actually two stories of origin of the character ‘美’.http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/daily-chinese-learning-tips/chinese-vocabulary-about-beauty/

Answer (score 0):

It means beauty/beautiful in Chinese, and it's spelling is měi, the third tone.

To better memorize it, you can take a look of my project before that has a transformation from its English letters to Chinese character.

http://gracegotlost.com/6-Steps-to-BEAUTY